# Facebook chat bot - catch post title or link sent by "Send message" button

Tags: node.js, facebook

I am creating chat bot for fb messenger, so far so good. I am facing the following problem: When I create new fb post using the request

```
{myPageID}/feed?message=For all Math geniuses :)&payload={"value":"test"}&call_to_action={"type":"MESSAGE_PAGE","value":"test"}&link=someLink&access_token={my_token}
```

I am attaching CTA Button "MESSAGE_PAGE" which add "Send message button to my post"
[image]

When I click on the button "Send message" I got auto-response from my page with link preview
[image]

I am subscribed for all messenger events and the only event I receive is delivery event. Is there any way I can catch the title or the link of this auto-response messenge? When I am posting with request I added payload, post back even value to the button and nothing is coming except this delivery event

Here is my receive message so far:

```js
app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {

  let body = req.body;  // Checks this is an event from a page subscription

  if (body.object === 'page') {
    // Iterates over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    body.entry.forEach(function (entry) {
      // Iterate over each messaging event
      entry.messaging.forEach(function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        if (event.message) {
          receivedMessage(event);
        }
        else if (event.delivery) {
          //TO DO
        }
        else {
          payloadMessage(event);
        }
      });
    });
    // Returns a '200 OK' response to all requests
    res.status(200).send('EVENT_RECEIVED');
  } else {
    // Returns a '404 Not Found' if event is not from a page subscription
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});
```

and this is the delivery event

```js
{ sender: { id: 'senderID' },
  recipient: { id: 'recipientID' },
  timestamp: 1558957571235,
  delivery: 
   { mids: 
      [ '8KsvyN2iL2upEhwddr_uQXeOJLgKhhdQtqQ8RzPxlPczGgR2T1w7Inqg8TJK-4gpWNQS-HZvLUBS5R-g1FcWdQ' ],
     watermark: 1558957571029,
     seq: 0 } }
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the message via the `mid`?

Comment: I haven't.. is there a place I can see example of the code or how to do that ?

Comment: Basic Graph API request using the message id …

Comment: I tried, message is empty string, subject is deprecated and on tags I don't get much info except source web

Comment: It is working actually, I didn't see there is /shares I was able to get the title. Thank you!